# How to respond to a fetch(post) with js.erb?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, fetch, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to make a post request that'll grab all events(Jams) and update dynamically the page via ajax. So my controller recieves params in JSON format and I'd like to respond with js just like how you would do with remote: true on a link or button.

I am using rails 6.0.2.2

This is in my .js file =>

```
const getJams = () => {
  const mapCenter = map.getCenter();
  const mapBounds = map.getBounds();
  const token = document.getElementsByName("csrf-token")[0].content
  fetch(window.location.origin + "/search", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Accept': "text/javascript",
      'Content-Type': "application/javascript",
      'X-CSRF-Token': token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      map_center: mapCenter,
      max_lat: mapBounds._ne.lat,
      min_lat: mapBounds._sw.lat,
      max_lng: mapBounds._ne.lng,
      min_lng: mapBounds._sw.lng
    }),
    credentials: "same-origin"
  })
}
```

The method in the search controller where the data is sent is like this =>

```
def index
    @jams = policy_scope(Jam)

    respond_to do |f|
      f.json do |f|
        render json: {
          jams: render_to_string(
            partial: 'jams/jams',
            formats: :html,
            layout: false,
            locals: { jams: @jams }
          )
        }
      end
    end
  end
```

Executed like this, inside my byebug the params are present, so that seems correct. If I continue my server shows me this

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 889)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/searchs_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

I'd like to work inside that search.js.erb file to append the elements inside my view. Though, my search.js.erb contains simply `console.log("a");` but that js seems not to be executed. Nothing appears in the console.

If anyone could help me I'd be grateful.

Here is the inside of the jams/_jam.html.erb partial =>

```
<% jams.each do |jam| %>
<div class="jam-card">
  <%= image_tag jam.photo %>
  <%= jam.status %>
  <%= jam.user.first_name %>
  <%= jam.music_style.music_style %>
  <%= display_date(jam.start_date_time, jam.duration) %>
  <%= jam.participants.count %>/<%= jam.max_participants %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint. You don't need `js.erb` templates.

- They make an absolute mess of the flow. When you reach for a `js.erb` template you're now context switching between Ruby and JavaScript and server side and client side on every line. This mental gymnasics does not promote good quality code.
- `js.erb` templates are not served by the assets pipe/webpacker and are thus not minified or served by a CDN.
- You know that nice restful server side app you carefully crafted? Kiss it goodbye because its now responsible for client side transformations and full of wiggle the woggle routes and spagetti code javascript views.

Either respond to the request with an array of JSON objects and let the client side handle templating or pass a HTML string back in the JSON response and let your real ajax handler actually do its job:

```
def index
  @jams = policy_scope(Jam)
  respond_to do |f|
    f.json do 
      render json: { 
        jams: render_to_string(
          partial: 'jams/jams', 
          formats: :html, 
          layout: false, 
          locals: { jams: @jams}
        )
     }
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
.then(function(response) {
  document.getElementById("some_element").innerHTML = response;
})
```

There are also approaches where people have used `request.xhr` to send back chunks of HTML in response to a HTML ajax request or used custom content types. All of them are better then `js.erb`.

Comment: I've edited the post to show the updated files using your method. Thanks already it gives me some way of continuing !

Comment: If you look at the logs the first line should read something like "Processing as <format>". What format is it looking for?

Comment: Processing by SearchsController#index as JS

It's processing as JS now so in the fetch request I should change it again to json ?

Comment: Ah of course  - you're sending `Accept: "text/javascript"`. Just change the accept & content type in your ajax call to `"application/json"`. You only really need content type though. The other is implied.

Comment: Oh man ! It works ! That's amazing, you saved me ! Goodbye js.erb's. I'm just beginning to code and they said always to use remote: true and js.erb. I didn't know we could call a partial inside of the render json: ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Whoever said that is someone you should be very sceptical of.